# Redirect 301: URL with parameter without value

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-parameters

I have a little problem with my 301 redirects.

I have this URL,

```
https://www.example.com/directory/?rapidoysencillo
```

and I need to redirect to,

```
https://www.example.com/directory?provenanceCode=myprovenance
```

I tried to use

```
RewriteCond `%{QUERY_STRING} ^rapidoysencillo=([^&]+)
```

but didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rapidoysencillo$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?provenanceCode=myprovenance [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much @anubhava